# Duda sobre Gema Devise Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Querría saber si alguien me puede dar una mano con esto.. Tengo un problema con devise ya que no encotnre la forma de listar mis usuarios y modificarlos con un administrador.. básicamente es buscar el con el admin al  usuario y asignarle su rol correspondiente que por defecto es Usuario, son 3 mis roles "Tarifero" "Admin" y "Usuario" estos se asignan con un enunm

```
  enum role: [:admin, :tarifero, :user]
  after_initialize :set_default_role, :if => :new_record?

  def set_default_role
    self.role ||= :user
  end
```

De por si Devise es bastante bueno par esto de usuarios pero para modificarlo es bastante "Rebelde", si me pueden ayudar desde ya muchas gracias!!!..

Comment: A que te refieres con que es rebelde? Si quieres una interfaz para administrar tus usuarios, eso no es responsabilidad de devise. Para eso tendrías que crear tu propia interfaz de usuario o usar alguna gema como active_admin o rails_admin para gestionar las tablas que tu quieras.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según lo que leo existe un formulario en `/users/new` el cual tiene un **select** con los datos de tus roles `[:admin, :tarifero, :user]`.

Bueno existen varias formas para realizar lo que mencionas:

1.- Hacer dos validaciones en el modelo **User**:

```
validates :role, presence: true
validates_inclusion_of :role, :in => %w( admin, tarifero, user )
```

Para obligar al administrador a seleccionar una opción valida.

2.-Hacer diferentes formularios para User

`/admins/new`  y en el controlador hacer algo así:
`User.new role: "Admin"`

`/tariferos/new`  y en el controlador hacer algo así:
`User.new role: "Tariferos"`

`/users/new`  y en el controlador hacer algo así:
`User.new role: "User"`

3.- Hacer un modelo para cada tipo de usuario

Es decir agregar a la migración del User un atributo type el cual y hacer modelos (Admin, Tarifero) que  extiendan de User y así en cada modelo puedes hacer un callback el cual establezca el role al crear.

**OJO:** Esta opción lleva mas trabajo pero a lo mejor a la larga valga la pena tener la lógica de cada usuario separada.

Saludos! espero ayudarte en algo!

Comment: Muchas gracias probe  la primera opcion y fue perfecto! Muchas gracias!

Comment: Que bueno que te sirbio amigo!                                                                     Seria bueno que pudieras votar la respuesta con una flecha arriba, saludos!

Comment: Estoy trarando de votar pero creo que no me deja por ser nuevo.... me aparece este mensaje "¡Gracias por tu comentario! Los votos emitidos por quienes tienen menos de 15 de reputación se registran, pero no cambian la puntuación que se muestra públicamente."

Comment: Aaa no sabía! Gracias MarceloT seguimos en contacto!